# How can I make a static asset conditional with vite?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vite, assets

I am currently building an app with tauri and I was requested to create a version of the app that doesn't contain the the larger assets. I want to know if I can automate something like this with vite (Some kind of build argument that can be used to changes the code at compile time)

(In rust the solution would be features)

When I played around a bit I saw that vite doesn't add assets that weren't imported in the code into the bundle.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.